# Fortran .mod files becoming too large

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

In our Fortran project we are making extensive use of modules, since we are doing object oriented programming in Fortran 2003. We now have a hierarchy of objects with approximately 7 different levels. The problem for us is that the modules and files in the high levels take quite long to compile, even if they consist of only a few lines.

Looking at the created files, I think that the probable cause for this are the very large .mod files being written. Exploring these files (for gfortran 4.6 for instance) I can see that the complete interfaces for all the objects and modules recursively being used are included in each high level .mod file. These files are much smaller in gfortran 4.9, where they are stored in compressed format, but still they are quite large and slow down the compile times.

We have tried using private statements in each module (so that the underlying used modules cannot be seen just by using the current module) but this doesn't affect the size of the resulting .mod files.

Is there any programming practice or compiler directive which can solve this issue?

Comment: This is highly compiler specific. Different compilers have different approaches. Some compilers do not include everything and have a link to the other module file. Some compilers do not use module files at all (Cray by default)! Gfortran's module format changes from version to version and I am not aware of any directive that can change the format.

Comment: If you want any comments or advice about your current programming practise, that would be on-topic in CodeReview.stackexchange (hi chat robot ;)) and you definitely must show your code.

Comment: @VladimirF Advice about different styles of programming would be more appropriate for programmers.SE. Advice on his current code can be asked for on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but he would need to disclose the code. My gut tells me that may be a problem.

Comment: @Mast The robot works! Notice my "and you definitely must show your code"

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF. It is good to know that the issue is compiler specific and might be improved in future releases of the compiler.